# nfs on ubuntu 17.04 works but not on 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

no problem with 17.04 or earlier
nfs on 17.10 does not work with no changes between upgrade.

the error / problem:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 46.101.44.101:/var/www
```

my nfs install routine:
server: (fresh 17.10 install)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server --yes
sudo mkdir -p /var/www
sudo nano /etc/exports
    /var/www 178.62.77.174(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

sudo exportfs -a
sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart
```

client: 17.10

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/nfs/test
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/nfs/test/www
sudo mount 46.101.44.101:/var/www /mnt/nfs/test/www

sudo nano /etc/fstab
    46.101.44.101:/var/www /mnt/nfs/test/www/ nfs auto,noatime,nolock,bg,nfsvers=4,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
```

this exact process works for 17.04, but not 17.10
any help appreciated.

Edit:
on client, the share is seen, just not able to mount:

```
showmount -e 46.101.44.101
Export list for 46.101.44.101:
/var/www 178.62.77.174

mount 46.101.44.101:/var/www /mnt/nfs/test/www
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 46.101.44.101:/var/www
```

Comment: Hmmm. OK. Are there firewalls in the way?

Comment: ufw is off.  There is a cloud firewall but port 2049 is open.  I have also added to the post - the client can definitely see the host's export... just not mount.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72514/discussion-between-shadeblack-and-michael-hampton).

Comment: Have you found the solution to this issue?

Comment: A solution was never found for 17.10, ended up moving to 18.04 lts